# Transmission slips into neutral

Tags: transmission, dodge, grand-caravan

I have a 2002 grand caravan it goes about 50 feet then just act like it's in neutral I can turn it off put it in park start back up and it goes about another 50 feeding does it again anybody know why this is happening

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Have you checked the transmission fluid to ensure it's where it should be?

Comment: Any transmission codes in the computer? Is it full on fluid?

Comment: Have you checked the motor mounts?  With a chock block in front and behind the front wheel, have someone shift from forward to reverse and back to forward. Does the motor seem to move excessively? A bad motor mount may allow the motor to move enough to shift it out of gear.